# Performance when using SAPbobsCOM.Company in Local vs External class

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, visual-studio-2019, sap-business-one-di-api

I use this code to load data from SAP DI (SQL Query) to a DataTable:

```
namespace SAPApp
{
    class SAPData
    {
    public void GetSAPData(Company oCompany)
        {
            if (oCompany.Connected)
            {
                dt.TableName = _TableName;
                DataColumn dtColumn;
                DataRow dtRow;

                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                SAPbobsCOM.Recordset oRecordSet;

                oRecordSet = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
                oRecordSet.DoQuery(SQL); 
                oRecordSet.MoveFirst();

                dt.BeginLoadData();
                int colCount = oRecordSet.Fields.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    string colName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(i).Name;
                    BoFieldTypes ftype = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(i).Type;
                    var dType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                    if (ftype == BoFieldTypes.db_Date)
                        dType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
                    else if (ftype == BoFieldTypes.db_Numeric)
                        dType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal");

                    dtColumn = new DataColumn()
                    {
                        DataType = dType,
                        ColumnName = colName,
                        Caption = colName,
                    };
                    dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);
                }


                while (!oRecordSet.EoF)
                {
                    dtRow = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                        dtRow[i] = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(i).Value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                    oRecordSet.MoveNext();
                }
                dv = new DataView(dt);
                dt.EndLoadData();

                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
```

Works fine!. It takes 0.222 sec to execute when the SAPbobsCOM.company & Company.Connect() are defined "locally" in Main Form (single form app). But when I move the SAPbobsCOM.company object to an "external" class the same code run on +22 secs (Moving app to MDI).

Local declaration:

```
namespace SAPApp
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        private readonly Company oCompany = new Company();
...

// Call in main form

SAPData SDAcc = new SAPData;
SDAcc.GetSAPData(oCompany);  // param: oCompany object
```

External Declaration:

```
\\ First create a TSapDI with oCompany objet

namespace SAPApp.Commons
{
    public partial class TSapDI
    {
        public readonly Company oCompany = new Company();

\\ Then instantiate in Globals

namespace SAPApp.Commons
{
    internal class Globals
    {
        public static TSapDI SapDI = new TSapDI();

\\ Create method in Commons 

namespace SAPApp
{
    class SAPData
    {
    public void GetSAPData(Company oCompany)....

\\ Finally call it

SAPData SDSearch = new SAPData
SDSearch.GetSAPData(Globals.SapDI.oCompany); // param: Globals.SapDI.oCompany object
```

In first case VisualStudio can inspect oCompany object inside GetSAPData but in second can't.

Can someone help me understand why such a difference and if possible how to fix it? Thanks.

P.S. I think it has to do with oCompany changing from a static to a non-static object.

I need the code to be executed in less than 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the exact cause, but I finally updated the code to:

```
public static class TSapDI
{
    public static Company oCompany = new Company();
```

Then change all references from: Globals.SapDI.oCompany to TSapDI.oCompany and it was back to running in 0.222 seconds :-D

PS I need to change few other things to allow this change.